# Is there any way to automatically cast literal to text for a parameter defined as anyelement?

Tags: postgresql, casting

PostgreSQL is not so friendly with user in this case,

```
CREATE FUNCTION foo(anyelement)  RETURNS text AS $$
   SELECT 'The type is ' || pg_typeof($1); 
$$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;

SELECT foo(123); -- OK
SELECT foo('123'::text); -- OK
SELECT foo('123'); -- ERROR
```

There are an "option", a (low cost) workaround to avoid this kind of interruption?

Perhaps some "automatic casting" for literal-to-text convertion? In pg9+ no news about it?

Comment: You can to declare overloaded function additionally to yours with explicit parameter type: `CREATE FUNCTION foo(anyelement)  RETURNS text AS ...; CREATE FUNCTION foo(text)  RETURNS text AS ...;`

Answer (score 3):

In PostgreSQL the 'literal' notation is used to denote different types of data. For instance all the following expressions are correct and return a valid result of different type:

```
select ('123':: bytea)
select ('123':: money)
select ('123':: float)
select ('123':: text)
select ('123':: integer)
select ('123':: json)
...
```

so that the syntax `'123'` is inherently ambiguous, and Postgres does not provide any automatic convertion for, at least in the current version (and probably in future releases as well).

Comment: Thanks, good to confirm (!) the hypothesis of *"no support"*... I think it is not only a matter of "friendless", but also a perform question: there are situations (ex. configs) where a system use literals and the function will be perform an error, and the Exception Handling is a big overhead for functional performance and for "clean code" library.